# PHP separating numbers from string into an array

Tags: php

I am trying to separate numbers from a string like this:
*-4-25-30* with php

I have tried following things:

```
$fltr = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($q);$i++) {
    $odr = $q[$i]['odr'];
    $fltr = preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9_#-]{4,})/i', $odr, $matches);
}
```

this one gives an output: 1

and the explode function:

```
$fltr = array();        
for($i=0;$i<count($q);$i++){
    $odr = $q[$i]['odr'];
    $fltr = explode($odr, '-');
}
```

note: `$odr` contains the string.

this one gives an O/P: "-"

I want to fetch all the numbers from the string.

Comment: You can do this using `explode('-', trim('-4-25-30', '-'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$fltr = explode('-', trim($odr, '-'));
```

I think you mixed up the delimiter with the actual string when using `explode()`.

Answer (score 0):

As i comment, if you want to separate all the number from the string then you need to use `explode` function of `PHP`. also you need to use `trim` for remove the extra `-` from the string.

```
$arr = explode('-', trim('-4-25-30', '-'));
print_r($arr); //Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 25 [2] => 30 )
```

Also you can do this way,

```
$arr = array_filter(explode('-', '-4-25-30'));
print_r($arr); //Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 25 [2] => 30 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$odr="-4-25-30";
$str_array=explode("-",trim($odr,"-"));
foreach  ($str_array as $value){
printf("%d\n",$value);
}
?>
```

should get what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to combine all the examples from above with some fixes

```
<?php
$q = array(array('odr' => '-4-25-30'),);

$fltr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($q); $i++)
{
    $odr = $q[$i]['odr'];
    $fltr = preg_match_all('/(\d+)/i', $odr, $matches); // find 1 or more digits together
}

echo "attempt 1: \n";
echo "count: ";
var_export($fltr); // count of items
echo "\nmatches: ";
var_export($matches[0]); // array contains twice the same
echo "\n";

$fltr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($q); $i++)
{
    $odr = $q[$i]['odr'];
    $trim = trim($odr, '-'); // 2nd param is character to be trimed

    $fltr = explode('-', $trim); // 1st param is separator
}

echo "attempt 2, explode: ";
var_export($fltr);
echo "\n";
```

Output:

```
attempt 1:
count: 3
matches: array (
  0 => '4',
  1 => '25',
  2 => '30',
)
attempt 2: array (
  0 => '4',
  1 => '25',
  2 => '30',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the needed result with `preg_match_all` function you may go via following approach:

```
$odr = "-4-25-30";
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+?\b/', $odr, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 25
    [2] => 30
)
```